# Listener (or handler) for video finish

Tags: android, media-player

I have implement the following code in order to test playing a video from a remote web server through it´s URL.

```
videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://sayedhashimi.com/downloads/android/movie.mp4"));
videoView.requestFocus();
```

The code is working just fine, even in the Android emulator. I just would like to know if there's any listener (or handler) to detect the finish of the video that is being reproduced?

#### Update:

I have the following code now:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.player);
        
    videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    playVideo();
        
    // video finish listener
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // not playVideo
            // playVideo();
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}

public void playVideo() {
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://sayedhashimi.com/downloads/android/movie.mp4"));
    videoView.requestFocus(); 
}
```

When the activity is just called, the video works fine but when the video finishes, I would like that it played again, which it's not occurring.

Comment: Instead of invoking `playVideo()` try calling `mp.start()`

Comment: Yes, I had already replaced it in my code.

Thank you for all the help!
Best regards!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Seems you are looking for

```
setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)
```

More in depth explanation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

#### EDIT

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/82bae0bbcee85fb4) shows a solution where playback is called after completion using `VideoView`, `MediaController` and `setOnCompletionListener()`.

Comment: But I'm not using MediaPlayer but yes MediaController. It's not kind of different?

Answer (score 21):

here is my working chunk of code:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {           
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                // Do whatever u need to do here

            }           
        });
```

Comment: i am using on complete listener but it is call when video is start

Answer (score 18):

```
        vidView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(null);
    vidView.setVideoPath( "/mnt/external_sd/somerandommovie.3gp" );
    vidView.start();

    vidView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        vidView.start();
        }
    });
```

I found that the listener was firing, the issue was mp.start() didn't seem to do anything, so calling start again on the original object seems to be working fine.

Comment: You just need to call mp.seekTo(0) before calling mp.start() to return to the beginning of the media file.

Answer (score 1):

in your onCompletion listener, try using videoView.start(); instead of mp.start();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the player on the main thread, it seems the callback only works on the main thread.