# catching movieend using VideoView

Tags: java, android-videoview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to play an Intro video to my android application.

So whenever my app starts, a movie is played until it ends or until the user touches the screen.

After that the user is forwarded to the menu activity.

So far I have the following:

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

private VideoView video;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.seaofbuttons);
    video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    video.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (video.isPlaying()) {
        video.stopPlayback();
    }
    Intent menu = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(menu);
    finish();
    return false;

}
}
```

I don't know how to catch when the movie playing ended, to be able to forward the user to menu activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "resource folder" + "videoname.format");
i think this should work
and for 2nd 
use setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l) 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

Comment: thanks. example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847818/listener-or-handler-for-video-finish