# How can I play videos consecutively using VideoView control?

Tags: android, video

I have a video playing using the VideoView control,

```
VideoView vid;

vid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);        
String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoviewdemo;
vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
vid.start();
```

which works fine, but I assumed incorrectly that calling setVideoURI() and start() would wait for the first video to finish before playing the second.  Is there any way to make the entire video play before moving on to the next line of code?  Thanks

(I just started Android/Java programming a few days ago, and haven't written software in ANY language for years, so forgive me if I'm a little slow)

Comment: Not understanding your exact requirement.

Comment: www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Video_Playback_on_Android_using_the_VideoView_and_MediaController_Classes

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the completion listener to play the next video.
it will trigger as soon as current video gets finished.

keep track of the currently running video in the global integer.
update it to keep the track of them and get the next video to play

check this link
[Listener (or handler) for video finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847818/listener-or-handler-for-video-finish)