# Videoview skipping videos just play the last one

Tags: android

I wanted to play the video which is on my server from database sql server i am getting all the name from volley which i do iterate to get the video name but the problem is the videoview skipa all the videos and play only the last one from my database

i have searched about it but not be able to find a good reason why it is doing that?

```
 public void Playvideo(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
         String link = "https://192.168.1.108/api/home/getvideos";
        VideoView vidView = findViewById(R.id.ad_video);
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, link, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for(int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String vide = jsonObject.getString("video");
                        String vidAddress = "https://192.168.1.108/Videos/"+vide;
                        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
                        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
                        vidView.start();


                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error",error.toString());
            }
        });
        RequestQueue queuee = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queuee.add(request);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop finishes so fast only the last video ends up getting displayed.

What you need to do is during the loop, wait until the first video finishes before allowing the loop to continue.

There are quite a few ways to do this sort of thing, but this is the general idea of what's happening.

Comment: can you post an example ?

Comment: i have used handler.postdelay to resolve the issue thank you :) just one more thing the delay time i have used is 30000millisec the problem is it is starting the first video after 30 sec can is there any possible way through which i can play the first video immediately and after that every 30sec delay ?

Comment: and how can i start the loop over again when response.length() reaches it end ?

Comment: @SohailShah Yeah, you really don't want to use a hardcoded value for this. The better way would be to be notified when the video stops playing. You should probably also create a way for the user to skip to the next video or go back to the previous video.

Check out this other answer for information on how to see when the video finishes playing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847862/940217

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion kyle :) but i am not making a video player, what i wanted is the video i want to play through loop should play till it does not end then the loop can plus an iteration then wait for the video to be end likewise when it reaches last iteration it should start it from the first i have tried searching and implemented different technique but  got stuck of doing all these things together